# Error when installing expo-cli using npm on macOS Big Sur

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

I am trying to install expo-cli on my mac but when I run the command `npm install -g expo-cli` I get this error

`npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:                                                                       npm ERR! peerOptional type-fest@"^0.13.1" from @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.3.3                  npm ERR! node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin                           npm ERR!   @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@"^0.3.3" from @expo/webpack-config@0.12.66                     npm ERR!   node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/webpack-config                                        npm ERR!     @expo/webpack-config@"0.12.66" from xdl@59.0.32                                                   npm ERR!     node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl                                                      npm ERR!       xdl@"59.0.32" from expo-cli@4.4.1                                                          npm ERR!       node_modules/expo-cli                                                                          npm ERR!       1 more (@expo/dev-tools)`

I tried running the command with `--force` but I got the same error. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: what version of npm are you running?
try updating `npm` first with `npm install -g npm`

Comment: thanks so much. this solved my problem.